# uncheck and check all checkboxes with a button in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, checkbox

I have a flask app that has a bunch of checkboxes, some of the pre-checked. I would like to have a button that checks/unchecks all the checkboxes.
I realized that I should do it with a javascript function, so I created a file script.js in the static folder and put these functions in it:

```
$("#check-all").click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',false);
});


$("#uncheck-all").click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',true);
})
```

This is the html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'script.js') }}"></script>
<div class="row" style="border:solid ; background-color:lightgray">
    <form method="POST" , action="{{ url_for('submitting') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <br>Please select detached object(s):<br>
            {% for o in data.objects %}
            <h4><input type="checkbox" name="word_objs" value="{{ o }}"> {{ o }} <br></h4>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="button" id="uncheck-all" value="UncheckAll"/>
            <input type="button" id="check-all" value="CheckAll"/><br>
        </div>
    </form>

    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

But unfortunately, none of them work. I would appreciate it if anyone helps me with it.

Comment: share the html page

Comment: Based on your question, you created a `script.js` but then linked `jvs/map.js` in the template. Are you loading the correct file?

Comment: yes, I am loading the correct file. It's a mistake in the question

Comment: You could try `$('#check-all").on('click', function() { ...` rather than .click(func()